# Restore of master key SSISD fails, not able to use SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My restore of master key for SSISDB is failing; I am not able to use my SSIDB for new or old packages. I need at least new packages to work.

At least I need my SSISDB to work, I can deploy new a Package and it should be run. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you first create an Integration Services Catalog, SSISDB, it asks for a database master key password. It's important to keep track of that password in the event you ever need to restore the SSISDB, you'll have to have it.

In your case, you've restored SSISDB elsewhere and it's of no use since you can't decrypt anything that is relying on Server encryption (which happens automatically when you deploy an ispac).

What can you do? Since we can't recover the original encryption passphrase, the only thing left to do is tear down the SSISDB and recreate it. 
Then recreate all the Folders
Then deploy all the Projects and Environments
Then apply any Configurations to Projects and/or Packages

Since it was a restore and broken from the get go, there *shouldn't* be any SQL Agent jobs to depending on the SSISDB.

[Behind the scenes with Integration Services Catalog Create](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2014/09/behind-scenes-with-integration-services.html)